# How to zero new random elements of a 3d array

Tags: objective-c, random, multidimensional-array, zero

I need an algorithm that takes some random elements from a 3d array and sets their value to zero , then without the possibility of selecting one of the elements that were picked, it goes on till a special quantity of elements are set to zero.
I know some ways that take lots of memory and operations. But i need something that can do it with least operation functioning.
Thanks a lot.
Oh... Forgot to say the language is Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for your answers . I'm going to test them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *alreadyPicked=[NSMutableArray new];
NSInteger loop=0;
while(loop<=array[0].count+array[1].count+array[2].count){
    NSInteger index0D=arc4random()%array[0].count;
    NSInteger index1D=arc4random()%array[1].count;
    NSInteger index2D=arc4random()%array[2].count;

    // pickedElement
    array[index0D][index1D][index2D]=0;
    NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithformat:@"%d,%d,%d",index0D,index1D,index2D];
    if(![alreadyPicked containsObject:temp]){
        [alreadyPicked addObject:temp];
        loop++1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the non-zero elements are only allowed in the array you use the following algorithm

```
-(void) randZeroMaker:(NSMutableArray*)array withNumberElements:(NSInteger*)count {
    while(count > 0){
        int x = randGen(array.length);
        int y = randGen([array objectAtIndex:0].length);
        int z = randGen([[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0].length);
        if ( [[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:z] == 0 ) {
            [[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:z] = 0;
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Please do correct me if I'm wrong!

This is O(1) in space and O(count + k) in time. Which I think is the best.

Comment: i think your if statement is meant to be a != instead of ==

Comment: yeah sorry about that @Fonix